# How to strip ' \n' in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code:

`String name='ishtiaq\n'`

How can I strip the newline-character?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is \n a newline char or literally "\n"

Comment: In yor example there is a `"."`, you want to remove that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "\n" always occurs at the end, use [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) [this won't remove the period, however, if you care about doing that]. If you want to eliminate internal newlines, you could use [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). You could also copy the string into a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or array to construct a new string, skipping over the elements you wish to discard, or you could locate the relevant indices and use [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to get a substring that excludes the elements you don't like. In short, there are many ways to do this.

Here is just one of many ways to do it (this one removing both the period symbol and the newline):

```
private static String nameWithoutSuffix(String nameWithSuffix) {
  int periodIndex = nameWithSuffix.indexOf('.');
  int newlineIndex = nameWithSuffix.indexOf('\n');
  if ((periodIndex == -1) && (newlineIndex == -1)) {
    return nameWithSuffix;
  }

  int suffixStartIndex = -1;
  if (periodIndex != -1) {
    suffixStartIndex = periodIndex;
  }
  if ((newlineIndex != -1)
      && ((suffixStartIndex == -1)
          || (newlineIndex < suffixStartIndex))) {
     suffixStartIndex = newlineIndex;
  }

  return nameWithSuffix.substring(0, suffixStartIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Michael Aaron Safyan , it works nicely, but sir why .replaceAll("\n"," ") and replace("\n"," ") did not work when i read data from file by line and store it in string array by words?

Comment: @ishtiaq replaceAll() and replace() should work, assuming that you are saving the return value of those functions (the original string on which you call the function is not modified; rather, a copy is created with those modifications and returned). It's also worth noting that some of those methods take a regular expression as a parameter, so you need to ensure that you use a valid regular expression that matches newlines than strictly a literal newline.

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings have `.replace`!

With it, your problem becomes super easy:

`String strippedString = name.replace("\n", "");`

**Remember**: When you use `replace`, Java won't work on the existing String. That's why you'll have to store the return-value in another object. (You could use the same of course.)

Comment: `replace('\n', '')` won't compile.

Comment: How doesn't it?

Comment: Empty character literal is invalid.

Comment: Excuse me, I fixed it. Dummy me :( It's because I'm from a python background and always use single quotes if the String or Char isn't a user readable one.

Comment: `replace('\n', "")` won't compile.

Comment: In what world? It does on my machine.

Comment: Screw that. Heck I'm rusty in Java. Excuse that and thank you. Jeez that's embarrassing.

Comment: Better. Good answer, but only *if* OP didn't intend to remove the `.` too. Inconsistency between question title and question text, but likely a typo in the question text.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too but figured it was a typo and suggested an edit. Cheeky me.

Comment: Sir it is working when it use it in my simple program. but when i read this data from a file and try to remove \n it does not work.

Comment: That probably means that your question was incomplete and you are not just dealing with newlines here.